# Not able to import firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, npm, npm-install

I downloaded firebase from (npm install firebase)

I used the script from Firebase to initialize the Firebase app:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

on my head tag but I am getting an error in my console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

can please anyone tell the fix to this error